# Detecting reflection in non-orthogonal rotation

Tags: rotation

I've known that, in orthogonal rotation, if the rotation matrix has determinant of -1 then reflection is present. Otherwise the determinant is +1 and we have pure rotation. May I extend this "sign-of-determinant" rule for non-orthogonal rotations? Such as orthogonal-into-oblique axes or oblique-into-orthogonal axes rotations? For example, this matrix

```
 .9427   .2544   .1665   .1377
-.0451  -.0902  -.9940  -.0421
 .3325   .3900   .1600   .8437
 .4052   .8702   .2269   .1644
```

is an oblique-to-orthogonal rotation (I think, because sums of squares in rows, not in columns, are 1). Its determinant is -0.524. May I state that the rotation contains a reflection? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just deleted my answer to reduce unnecessary noise. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the determinant is negative, composing with *any* reflection will give a positive determinant.  In that sense you are correct.  However, in another sense the question does not appear to be meaningful, because the matrix you give, although it is *row normalized,* is not orthogonal (it is not a "rotation," nor--unlike rotation matrices--can it be written as a finite product of reflections).  Whether or not it "contains" a reflection depends on what group you consider the matrix to be part of and what subgroup you want to relate it to, neither of which has been specified.

Comment: Why not a rotation matrix? It looks to me as a specific case of rotation though not orthogonal matrix. Consider factor analysis. We extract loadings A and oblimin-rotate the factors (axes) into oblique factors: S=A*Q where S is factor structure and Q is rotation matrix (with SS in its columns=1). Now, corresponding pattern matrix P=S*inv(Q'*Q)=A*inv(Q'), and so A=P*Q' which is backward, oblique-to-orto, rotation. The example matrix I posted was actually Q' rotating factor pattern matrix into factor loadings matrix. But my question was about whether sign of det of Q or Q' signals of reflection

Comment: @ttnphns There are several equivalent definitions of a rotation matrix, such as a finite composition of reflections or the matrix of a linear transformation that preserves the usual inner product.  Factor analysis terminology abuses this convention by extending the term "rotation" to matrices which manifestly are not rotations.  The interest of a reflection lies in the fact that the parity of the number of reflections needed to express a (true) rotation is a property of that rotation.  In effect, it is an element of the quotient group O(n)/SO(n).  You need a similar context for your matrices.

Comment: thank you a lot. I begin to understand why I'm speaking not same terms you do (you usage of terms is superior to mine). By reflection you mean bending a _point_ (vector) over a line (axis), while I was meaning a reflection of a coordinate _axis_ over origin by 180 degrees: central symmetry, that's what I meant by "reflection". And wanted to know: if the determinant was negative then could I state that a (oblique) rotation of _axes_ took place and "after that" one _axis_ changed its direction to the opposite direction.

Comment: @ttnphns A central symmetry in an even number of dimensions is not considered a "reflection" by anyone, not even you(!): its determinant will be positive.  (E.g., in 2D the central symmetry is a 180 degree rotation.)  The change of direction along *one* axis is a reflection.  Indeed, if you allow that "axis" to be any *hyperplane* through the origin (a "mirror", in effect), then you have described all the reflections.